# stopLeScan is ignored when called periodically in the background

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'd like my Android app to perform periodic LE scans even if the device is in deep sleep. For that purpose, I'm using an `Alarm Manager` which starts an `IntentService` which performs the scan.
As startLEScan() only informs of BLE devices once, and I'd like to get constant reports on near BLE devices, I need to stop and start the LE scan. This is my `IntentService` code:

```
   @Override
   protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
         _bluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(this); //I get it using BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
         try {
            Thread.sleep(2000); //I wait between a stop and a start
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Thread sleep interrupted!",e);
        }
         if (!_bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(this)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to scan");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG,"scan started");
        }
    }
```

When I run this code, I see that startLEScan() and stopLEScan() are called, but it apperas that stopLEScan() is ignored, because the BLE device I expect to find in the scan is found only once, and after several activations of the `IntentService` (the `Alarm Manager` triggers it every 4000 ms), I see the "Failed to scan" error, as if I have only sent startLEScan() requests without stopping the scan.

What, in your opinion, am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my opinion is that you are doing critical mistake:

using `IntentService` as facility for the background scan instead "regular" `Service`

IntentService.onHandleIntent() is been executed on a worker thread, and after it execution - unless it has more "waiting to be processed" intents in it queue - it will stopped itself automatically.

what it means - is that the scan callback would be executed (if at all)  after the `IntentService` is already destroyed!!!

you probably have "side affects" bugs that been caused by that..

in opposite to `IntentService` - a regular `Service` would not stopped when `onStartCommand()` will finish it execution.  it will be shout down only when you'll call explicitly the stopSelf() , or in case the system would be under extreme pressure to free memory..

Comment: But since I have no indication as to _when_ I should invoke `stopSelf()` (`BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED` isn't triggered for a BLE scan), this means that the `Service` will continue working and waste system resources, so my **periodic** stop/startLeScan() are meaningless, don't you think?

Comment: you are right that is no action or broadcast indicating that the scan complete, and you have to stop the scan yourself.  but that don't mean that using IntentService solving this problem.  you can post delayed Runnable with a handler, that stoppes the scan after 8-10 seconds.  that's exactly what the API's BLE demoes does.

Comment: Actually I've been using the `Handler.postDelayed()` method in my code up till now - but only for the foreground BLE scan. Since the `Handler` doesn't operate during the device's sleep, I can't use it, and must use the `AlarmManager` - or do you mean I should post a runnable from within the `Service` in order to time the `stopSelf()`?

Comment: @WarmChocolate: I didn't mean that you should user handler instead of AlarmService.   I said that you need to scedule with the alaram manager a pending intent to start Service instead of IntentService, and use a Handler inside the service to call asynchroniclly to stopSelf() and stopScan()